# Conda and Macports X11 conflicts when installing dlib

Tags: python, macports, conda, dlib

I am on a Mac 10.9.5, and I am trying to install dlib for python from here

http://dlib.net/files/dlib-18.16.tar.bz2

My python installation was made a long time ago, with `conda`:

```
Current conda install:

         platform : osx-64
    conda version : 3.16.0
 conda-build version : 1.3.5
   python version : 2.7.10.final.0
 requests version : 2.7.0
 root environment : //anaconda  (writable)
default environment : //anaconda
 envs directories : //anaconda/envs
    package cache : //anaconda/pkgs
     channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/
                    https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                    https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64/
                    https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
      config file : None
is foreign system : False
```

To install dlib I followed the following routine:

```
$ tar xvjf dlib-18.16.tar.bz2
$ cd dlib-18.16/python_examples/    
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ../../tools/python
$ cmake --build . --config Release --target install
```

as specified in the `compile_dlib_python_module.bat` file at `/Users/javier/dlib-18.16/python_examples`

I first got errors related with `Xlocale.h` and `Xosdefs.h`.

These files where found at `/opt/local/include/X11` and `/opt/X11/include/X11`. I copied those files into `/anaconda/include/X11` which I think solved the problem, since I am not getting error messages related to these two.

I run:

```
$ cmake --build . --config Release --target install
```

and now I get ***A LOT*** of error messages like:

```
 [  1%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/fonts.o

/Users/javier/dlib-18.16/dlib/gui_widgets/nativefont.h:313:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'XAllocColor'
                XAllocColor(d, cmap, &xcol);
/Users/javier/dlib-18.16/dlib/gui_widgets/nativefont.h:319:36: error: use of undeclared identifier 'XmbTextExtents'; did you mean 'XTextExtents'?
                        return XmbTextExtents(fs, str, len, ink, logical);
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                               XTextExtents
/Users/javier/dlib-18.16/dlib/gui_widgets/nativefont.h:318:43: note: 'XTextExtents' declared here
                    inline static int XTextExtents (XFontSet fs, char *str, int len, XRectangle *ink, XRectangle *logical){
```

All the related files, like `XmbTextExtents` are in `/opt/X11/share/man/man3`  and the zipped versions (`XmbTextExtents.3.gz`) are here `/opt/local/share/man/man3`.

The error raises from the fact that the dlib installation looks at `/anaconda/include/X11/` while it should look at `/opt/X11/include/X11` (I guess). I have tried to edit the relevant KEYS in the `CMakeCache.txt` file so they look as:

```
x11_path:FILEPATH=/opt/X11/include

//Path to a file.
xlib_path:PATH=/opt/X11/include/X11
```

But it does not work. I have been advised to start "fresh" with Homebrew (i.e. removing any trace from conda and macports and re-do the whole installation with Homebrew), but this looks like a rather drastic "solution" to me, also given the fact that I have **A LOT** of stuff installed already.

Just in case is of any use, the relevant lines in my .profile file look like this:

```
setenv PATH /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# anaconda path takes priority
setenv PATH /anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Try using the newer version of dlib.  You can also pip install dlib now as well and that ought to work.

Comment: Hi there David, thanks for your answer. pip install dlib throws the same error (since follows the same routine :) ) and the same goes for the newest version of dlib, since the problem is related to the X11 installation and the fact that cmake is looking at /anaconda/include and SHOULD NOT be looking at there. Changing the `CMakeCache.txt` file (as suggested in the instructions) has no effect for me. I might be doing something wrong. I am almost convinced to move to Homebrew.

Answer (score 4):

I deleted the `/anaconda/include/X11/` folder entirely and that did the trick.  dlib now builds no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by uninstalling anaconda